# How to activate tab when other tab is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I'd like to open tab 3 when category 2 is selected 
and open tab 1 when category 1 is selected

Does anybody knows how to do it?

[Here are the tabs](http://www.automatydrzwiowe.pl/trunk/index.php?event=product&parent_id=81&menu_id=2)

Thanks

Comment: where is tab1 ? and what about tab 4??

Comment: It would be easier if you prepared testcase on http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @diEcho tab1 is in category 1

Answer (score 1):

try adding `$('a [href="#tabs-403"]').click( function () { $('a [href="#tab3"]').click(); } );` to your `$.ready()` function.

Also, it would be easier to do this if you gave ids to the tabs, since the only identifiers between them at the moment is the `href` attribute

note: for anyone who didn't view the source on his example `$('a [href="#tabs-403"]')` selects the category 2 tab